# Help me understand why these ActiveRecord models throw exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

These are my models ( both only have a `name:string` attribute ):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subcategories
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
end
```

I started a `rails console`:

```
> c = Category.new(:name => "C1")
=> #<Category id:nil, name:"C1", created_at:nil, updated_at: nil>
> c.save
=> true
> s = c.subcategories.create(:name => "S1")
=> #<Subcategory id:2 name:"S1", created_at: "2011-03-16 17:45:18", updated_at: "2011-03-16 17:45:18">
> s.category
=> nil
> s.save
=> true
> c.subcategories
=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column subcategories.category_id: SELECT "subcategories".* FROM "subcategories" WHERE("subcategories".category_id = 2)
```

Why is `s.category` nil? Why do I receive the SQLException? Is there something wrong with my models? I'm going for a one to many association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Subcategory table is missing the category_id column which it needs to associate the record with a category. Create a migration to add it like so:

```
# Rails 3
rails g migration AddCategoryIdToSubcategories category_id:integer

# Rails 2
script/generate migration AddCategoryIdToSubcategories category_id:integer
```

Then run your migrations and it should work.

Comment: Shouldn't the `belongs_to` and `has_many` do that automatically?

Comment: @Geo No, you have to do it yourself in a migration.

Answer (score -1):

Yes... It will give the problem because c.subcategories always return an array(might be blank)
You can try like this.

```
 c = Category.new(:name => "C1")
 s = Subcategory.new(:name => "S1")
 c.subcategories = [s]
 c.save
```

Hope it will work.